# Can't create a node with label in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, label

I'm trying to create nodes in `Neo4j` with `Java`. 
If I try to add a `label` to a `node` by:

```
node.addLabel(Labels.hostname);
```

But no label is added to the nodes.

If I try adding `labels` by:

```
node = graphDb.createNode(Labels.hostname);
```

The nodes won't be created at all, Is there a solution? At the moment I'm creating my nodes like below, but I need labels on my nodes.

```
Node node = null;
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try
{
    node = graphDb.createNode(); 
    node.setProperty("sources_id", id);
    node.setProperty("domain", domain);
    node.setProperty("eivi", eivi);
    node.setProperty("hostname", hostname);
    node.addLabel(Labels.hostname);

    tx.success(); 

} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    tx.finish();
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you by chance have a nested TX where you don't mark the outer tx as successful and also `.finish/.close` it ?

You use a normal plain Neo4j embedded Database? How do you assert that no labels are added to your nodes? With a query or a by-label lookup?

Comment: My current set up is a remote neo4j server that is completely empty. I am trying to add these nodes by doing a single TX and i assert by doing a by-label lookup and with a query in the neo4j browser.

Comment: I also tried `node.addLabel(Labels.hostname)` in a single TX. But then i got an exception:

`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode.addLabel(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Label;)V`

Answer (score 0):

What is the Labels class you are referencing? the node.addLabel method takes a Label object, not a string.